# SQL Sorting With Overlap

Tags: sql, sorting, overlap

I have a table containing a list of indicies and values

`OrigTable`

```
Index     Value
  1        10
  2        11
  3        16
  4        18
  5        14
  6        11
  7        10
  8        12
  9        20
 10        17
```

I need to use two other tables to separate the values.

`Table1` will contain rows from `OrigTable` where `Value` is <=15, and

`Table2` will contain >15, but also containing one point in either direction such that if index *n* corresponds to a value above 15, it will be included in Table 2, but so will indicies *n-1* and *n+1*

as such the result will

`Table1`:

```
Index    Value
  1        10
  2        11
  5        14
  6        11
  7        10
  8        12
```

`Table2`:

```
Index    Value
  2        11
  3        16
  4        18
  5        14
  8        12
  9        20
 10        17
```

I haven't been able to determine a way to do this using SQL. Is it not possible, or am I missing some command that would make this doable?

EDIT: 15 would be included in Table 1; I forgot to add 'or equal to'. By 'one point in either direction', I meant that if index *n* corresponds to a value above 15, it will be included in Table 2, but so will indicies *n-1* and *n+1*

Comment: Why is Index 2 in two tables? and what exactly do you mean by `also containing one point in either direction`

Comment: what about poor 15, where does she go if she is extant

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? sql server <> mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table OrigTable
( 
theIndex int not null,
theValue int not null
);

insert into OrigTable (theIndex,theValue) values (1,10),(2,11),(3,16),(4,18),(5,14),(6,11),(7,10),(8,12),(9,20),(10,17);
-- select * from OrigTable;

create table table1
( 
theIndex int not null,
theValue int not null
);

create table table2
( 
theIndex int not null,
theValue int not null
);

insert into table1 (theIndex,theValue) select theIndex,theValue from OrigTable where theValue<=15;

insert into table2 (theIndex,theValue) select theIndex,theValue from OrigTable where theValue>15;

insert into table2 (theIndex,theValue) 
select a.theIndex,a.theValue 
from table2 b
join OrigTable a
on a.theIndex=b.theIndex-1
where a.theIndex not in (select theIndex from table2)

insert into table2 (theIndex,theValue) 
select a.theIndex,a.theValue 
from table2 b
join OrigTable a
on a.theIndex=b.theIndex+1
where a.theIndex not in (select theIndex from table2)



select * from table1 order by theIndex
select * from table2 order by theIndex
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need one point, and it might not be 15.  So, for the first query:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.value <= 15
```

And for the second:

```
(select t.*
 from table t
 where t.value <= 15
 order by t.value desc
 limit 1
) union all
(select t.*
 from table t
 where t.value > 15
)
```